# Comparing similar objects in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

What is the best way to compare two similar objects?

Given `FlintlockDTO` and `Flintlock`:

```
public class FlintlockDTO
{
  public string GName { get; set; }

  public string SharedPropertyName { get; set; }

  ...
}
```

and

```
public class Flintlock
{
  public Flintlock(FlintlockDTO inflator)
  {
    this.GoodName = inflator.GName;
    this.SharedPropertyName = inflator.SharedPropertyName;
    ...
  }

  public string GoodName { get; private set; }

  public string SharedPropertyName { get; private set; }
  ...
}
```

Where both classes share N properties (e.g. `SharedPropertyName`), but differ on M properties that are equivalent, but named differently (e.g. `GoodName` \ `GName`.)

Tools such as [fluentassert](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#object-graph-comparison) nearly do this, if the property names matched, to my understanding this would work:

```
flintlockDto.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(flintlock);
```

Is there a way to do this neatly in fluentassert or any other tool?

Ideally,

```
flintlockDto.IsTheSameAs(flintlock).WhenMapping("GName","GoodName");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to elaborate more about [Likeness](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/06/29/IntroducingAutoFixtureLikeness/) mentioned by StriplingWarrior. It's available as a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SemanticComparison/).

Here is an example:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Ploeh.SemanticComparison;
using Ploeh.SemanticComparison.Fluent;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    class Tests2
    {
        [Test]
        public void ObjectsShuldEqual()
        {
            var flintlockDto = new FlintlockDTO()
            {
                GName = "name",
                AdditionalProperty = "whatever",
                SharedPropertyName = "prop name"
            };
            var flintlock = new Flintlock(flintlockDto);

            Likeness<Flintlock, FlintlockDTO> flintFlockDtoLikeness = flintlock
                .AsSource().OfLikeness<FlintlockDTO>()
                .With(dto => dto.GName).EqualsWhen((flintlock1, dto) => flintlock1.GoodName == dto.GName) // you can write an extension method to encapsulate it
                .Without(dto => dto.AdditionalProperty);

            // assert
            flintFlockDtoLikeness.ShouldEqual(flintlockDto);
        }
    }

    public class FlintlockDTO
    {
        public string GName { get; set; }

        public string SharedPropertyName { get; set; }

        public string AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Flintlock
    {
        public Flintlock(FlintlockDTO inflator)
        {
            this.GoodName = inflator.GName;
            this.SharedPropertyName = inflator.SharedPropertyName;
        }

        public string GoodName { get; private set; }

        public string SharedPropertyName { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see:

- It performs auto comparison on properties with the same names
- You can specify if properties of different names should match (this one is actually pretty ugly out of the box, but you can write an extension method to encapsulate it)
- You can specify if a property should not be compared

Answer (score 2):

One strategy that I sometimes use when there are specific properties I want to compare together is to leverage anonymous types, like so:

```
Assert.AreEqual(
    new{flintlockDto.GoodName, flintlockDto.SharedPropertyName},
    new{GoodName = flintlock.GName, flintlock.SharedPropertyName});
```

This doesn't rely on any particular testing framework. It leverages the auto-generated `Equals()` methods for anonymous types, and in the case of failure the auto-generated `ToString()` method gives you a full description of what the two objects looked like, which makes it easy to figure out what went wrong.

You may also want to look into Mark Seemann's [Likeness](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/06/29/IntroducingAutoFixtureLikeness/) type:

> How do we resolve this conundrum without introducing equality pollution? AutoFixture offers one option in the form of the generic Likeness class. This class offers convention-based test-specific equality mapping from TSource to TDestination and overriding the Equals method.
>
> ... It's possible to customize the comparison to override the behavior for certain properties...

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension class/method inside your test project and achieve your desired result, and you won't pollute your production codebase with unnecessary logic.

```
static class Extensions
{
  public static bool IsEqualTo(this FlintlockDTO expected, Flintlock actual) 
  {
    return expected.GName == actual.GoodName && expected.SharedPropertyName == actual.SharedPropertyName;
  }
}
```

In your test, then you'll be able to run this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.IsEqualTo(actual));
```

and the test logic won't be available in your production codebase.

Answer (score 0):

It might be good to have `FlintlockDTO` implement `IEquatable<Flintlock>` as follows:

```
public override Equals(Flintlock other)
{
    return GName == other.GoodName; // modify as necessary (case, culture, etc.)
}
```

(And don't forget to override and properly implement `GetHashCode`.)

Then, you can just check if

```
flintlockDto.Equals(flintlock)
```

in the unit testing framework of your choice.

Comment: I would feel really uncomfortable giving people the impression that two objects of different types are "Equal". Also, this signature doesn't override the `Equals(object)` signature, so it wouldn't actually work with most test frameworks' `AreEqual()` assertions. And, to maintain parity, would you also need to implement the same equality check in the Flintlock class, going the other direction?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: But that's exactly what the OP wants to test for. And even though they are different types, they represent the same information - one is just a Data Transfer Object for the other.

Comment: Yes, but changing the Equals() and GetHashCode() behavior of two separate production classes seems like a lot of Test-Induced Damage to accommodate a basic unit test.

Comment: Overriding `Equals` in this case would only affect the comparison from `FlintlockDTO` to `Flintlock`, which is what the OP is trying to assert in the tests. It is also more maintainable - no hard-coded property names as strings and no individual property checking in the test methods.

Comment: Allowing your tests to impact production code in this way is an anti-pattern known as ["Equality Pollution"](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html#Equality%20Pollution). There are other, more composable, ways to keep this check maintainable, while still keeping your equality check [test-specific](http://xunitpatterns.com/test-specific%20equality.html)